# Кортежи и словари

Tags: python, словари, список, кортежи

Зачем нужны кортежи и словари, если есть список ?
Может у них есть какие-то свои особенности ?
Можете сказать, пожалуйста?

Comment: Кортежи быстрее и экономичнее, потому что неизменяемые. Словари хранят пары ключ-значение и дают доступ к значению по ключу, что в списках невозможно (или возможно только с огромной потерей производительности)

Comment: зачем нужен холодильник, если есть телевизор?

Comment: Не топите вопрос, нет ничего плохого в односложных, но практических вопросах, в том числе и для новичков

Answer (score 4):

#### Про словарь:

Словарь служит для хранения пар значений, где по первому значению в паре (ключу) можно получить второе значение.

Почему не использовать просто список с парами значений, и искать нужные значения просто циклом?

Потому что длительность поиска нужного объекта в списке будет пропорциональна длине списка (в среднем нужно дойти до середины списка, пока найдешь нужный объект), скорость поиска ключа в словаре (или объекта в множестве) практически не зависит от размера словаря или множества (время примерно константно).

Это свойство достигается тем, что словари и множества реализуется как хеш-таблицы, про которые можно почитать [в википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A5%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0), еще лучше - почитать какую-нибудь книгу по алгоритмам и структурам данных.

#### По поводу кортежей:

1. Они неизменяемы (иммутабельны)
2. и хешируемы (если содержат только хешируемые элементы) - значит могут быть ключами в словаре или элементами множеств (в отличие от списков).
3. и еще небольшой бонус - они занимают немного меньше места в памяти

По теме рекомендую почитать статью на Хабре:
[В каких случаях не нужно использовать списки в Python](https://habr.com/ru/company/otus/blog/510350/)

Answer (score 1):

Первое, сравнивать словарь со списком или кортежем не верно. У него свой функционал и применение.

Второе, кортеж - неизменяемый тип данных, а список - изменяемый. В остальном они похожи. Оба итерируемые (то есть можно пробежаться по всем членам сущности) и упорядоченные (каждый элемент имеет свое место и индекс, порядковый номер этого места)

```py
list_ = [1,2,3]
list_.remove(1)
print(list_)
# OUT
# [2, 3]
```

с кортежем такое провернуть нельзя, как и любые другие изменения.

Например сортировать

```py
list_ = [3,1,2]
list_.sort()
print(list_)
# OUT
# [1, 2, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Списки в Python - упорядоченные изменяемые коллекции объектов произвольных типов (почти как массив, но типы могут отличаться).
пример
list('список')
['с', 'п', 'и', 'с', 'о', 'к']

Кортеж, по сути - неизменяемый список. Зачем нужны кортежи, если есть списки? Защита от дурака. То есть кортеж защищен от изменений, как намеренных (что плохо), так и случайных (что хорошо).
Меньший размер. Возможность использовать кортежи в качестве ключей словаря.
пример d = {(1, 1, 1) : 1}

Словари в Python - неупорядоченные коллекции произвольных объектов с доступом по ключу. Их иногда ещё называют ассоциативными массивами или хеш-таблицами.
пример d = {'dict': 1, 'dictionary': 2}

Comment: Это не ответ, а комментарий.

Comment: ну да, конкретный ответ уже дали

Comment: заменил сообщение